# How to validate the form with jquery before the HTML 5 validation

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form in the Arabic language, i try to validate it with 2 ways: html 5 and j query also.
The problem is the English HTML 5  alert Appears in the first before that the arabic j query alert appears, but in my case i want the opposite with some change.
I want that the arabic j query alert appears in the first, and the HTML 5  English alert appears only if the j query can't stop the Cheating of user.. thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>j query_validation</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<form id="formId">
<input type="text" class="input-string" required/>
<input type="submit"/>
<p class="alert-error" style="display: 
none">can't be empty</p>
</form>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
 <script>
 $('#formId').submit(function(e){
 var inputValue = $('.input-string').val().length;
 if(inputValue == 0)
 {
    $('.alert-error').show();
    e.preventDefault();
}
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put e.preventDefault() at the start of your function.

This prevents any default form submission behaviour. Just remember to actually submit the form if it's successful.

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var inputValue;
 $('.input-string').each(function(){ // If you're checking for class, you may want to include this .each function, as many elements can have the same class. If you switch to ID, this can be removed.
 inputValue += $(this).val().length;
     }); // End .each

 if(inputValue == 0){        
    $('.alert-error').show();        
    }
 else{
    $('.alert-error').hide(); // Not really necessary if you're submitting and refreshing anyway, but it lets the user know it will be submitted successfully, before the page actually refreshed.
    form.submit();
    }

}); // End .submit
```

EDIT : Attached below is my the full answer, as per OP's request to fulfil further requirements in comments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>j query_validation</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formId">
    <input type="text" class="input-string" required/>
    <button id="test-button" type="button" role="button">Test Me </button>
    <p class="alert-error" style="display: 
none">can't be empty</p>
  </form>

  <script>
    $('#test-button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var inputValue = 0;
      $('.input-string').each(function() { // If you're checking for class, you may want to include this .each function, as many elements can have the same class. If you switch to ID, this can be removed.
        inputValue += $(this).val().length;
      }); // End .each
      // inputValue = 0; 
      if (inputValue == 0) {
        $('.alert-error').each(function() {
          $(this).css("display", "block");
        });
      } else {
        $('.alert-error').each(function() {
          $(this).css("display", "none"); // Not really necessary if you're submitting and refreshing anyway, but it lets the user know it will be submitted successfully, before the page actually refreshed.
        });

        $("#formId").submit();
      }

    }); // End .submit
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $('.input string') should be $('.input-string')

Comment: thanks for your help, but in your code if the user for example make the JavaScript disabled the the html 5 alert doesn't appears and stop the user – cmprogram

Comment: @NassimNasri That's correct, but a different question altogether. In that case, you can remove the button type "submit" and change it to button type="button" role ="button" and simply add an onclick event, or an onclick listener. After that, the code can remain unchanged.

Comment: @ cmprogram please if you have a little time can you change your code to this idea because  that what i would like to do

Comment: @ cmprogram thanks a lot very helpful, i did it:  $('button').click(function(e)
 {
     e.preventDefault();
     var inputValue = $('.input-string').val().length;
     if(inputValue == 0)
     {
        $('.alert-error').show();
     }
});

Comment: @NassimNasri If it worked for you, please accept the answer so that other users know this is the appropriate solution.

Comment: @cmprogram but the correct answer for me is in your comment not in your answer, i think it's not correctly to improve the answer and let the comment that has the correct answer

Comment: @NassimNasri And you should not ask additional questions in comments, as each question should be identified and explained in the question itself. Regardless, I have amended the answer now to answer your newer questions.

Comment: @cmprogram  please in your final  code you did a little error : button type="submit"  not button : so please correct this little error to improve your answer

Comment: @NassimNasri This isn't an error, it doesn't have to be type submit because you're submitting it through jQuery. If you make it of type submit, then it WILL submit if JavaScript is disabled, which is what you didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

there are two errors in your js

```
 $('#formId').submit(function(e){
     var inputValue = $('.input string').val().length;
     if(inputValue == ''){
        $('.alert-error').show();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

length: you cant use int as string
$('.input string'): should be $('.input-string'), you didn't add dash
change it to

```
 $('#formId').submit(function(e){
     var inputValue = $('.input-string').val().length;
     if(inputValue === 0){
        $('.alert-error').show();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```